# Валидация ширины и высоты изображения на сервере Node.js

Tags: node.js

Всем привет! Задали такую задачу: необходимо с админки сайта создавать папки под изображения, указывая в описании максимальные и минимальные размеры - ширину и высоту в пикселях. Соответственно при загрузке изображений ширина и высота должны проверяться. Однако в оригинальном объекте upload отсутствуют данные о ширине и высоте, только размер, тип и подтип.

Если честно, я даже не знаю как это правильно загуглить. Помогите превратить upload в картинку и получить её размеры на стороне сервера.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для этого нужен объект с картинкой где в свойствах и можно будет узнать по подробнее что за картинка, что-то вроде обьекта Image в браузере. С ходу нашел вот этот пакет для чтения изображений https://www.npmjs.com/package/readimage для Node.

Comment: Спасибо) Правда я уже успел разобраться с Jimp, но всё равно спасибо